# is there an 'upwards' find?

Tags: linux, unix, find, command-line-interface

To find files starting from a certain path, I can use `find <path> ...`.  If I want to find 'upwards', i.e. in the parent directory, and it's parent, and..., is there an equivalent tool?

Intended usage for a folder structure like this:

```
/
/abc
/abc/dce/efg/ghi


$ cd /abc/dce/efg/ghi
$ touch ../../x.txt
$ upfind . -name X*
../../x.txt
$ upfind . -name Y*
$
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this ?

Comment: Surely: I have a makefile that needs to know the path to a common piece of code implemented in a makefile somewhere up the chain.

Comment: @Iain: ... and I need to know the number of dots I have to type in to reach it.  A common problem, I assumed.

Comment: Possible same on unix SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/find-searching-in-parent-directories-instead-of-subdirectories

Answer (score 1):

```
x="$(pwd)"; while [ "$x" != "/" ]; do if [ -e "${x}/X.txt" ]; then echo $x; fi; x="$(dirname "$x")"; done
```

Comment: You missed an `fi;`

Comment: I surerly like the attempt, but I think it needs an `else`, too (`x` is only changed if the file is found).  And the part where the path is expressed relatively to the current working dir isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a downward-recursive `find` from `/`?  They will both search the entire filespace.  Or are you asking for one that travels up **but then does not travel down in the directories it finds in that search**?

Comment: Indeed: the latter.  Actually I want to find the parent dir that contains X.txt.

Comment: @xtofl cd ..;find blah?

Comment: @pauska: no, since then I could find blah in a sibling directory, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent directory of the file you can use `find` and the `-printf %h` argument

```
find /abc -name X.txt -printf "%h\n"
/abc/dce
```

- %h

  > Leading directories of file’s name (all but the last ele-
  >                    ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
  >                    in the current directory) the  %h  specifier  expands  to
  >                    ".".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Idea](https://serverfault.com/a/412456/62815) of @Womble, I wrote a small script that does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rfind: finds a file in one of the parent directories

needle=$1 
current_dir=$(pwd) 
path=

while [ "$current_dir" != "$(dirname $current_dir)" ]; do 
    if [ -e "${current_dir}/$needle" ]; then 
        echo $path$needle
        exit 0
    else 
        path=../$path
        current_dir="$(dirname "$current_dir")"
    fi
done

if [ ! "$current_dir" != "$(dirname $current_dir)" ]; then
    echo "rfind: file $needle not found" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

And named it 'rfind' in my own ~/bin directory.  It does the trick:

```
/tmp $ mkdir -p x/y/z
/tmp $ cd x/y/z/
/tmp/x/y/z $ rfind a.txt || echo "not found."
rfind: file a.txt not found
not found.
/tmp/x/y/z $ touch ../../a.txt
/tmp/x/y/z $ rfind a.txt || echo "not found."
../../a.txt
/tmp/x/y/z $ 
/tmp/x/y/z $ cd ..
/tmp/x/y $ mkdir z2
/tmp/x/y $ cd z
/tmp/x/y/z $ touch ../z2/a.txt
/tmp/x/y/z $ rfind a.txt || echo "not found."
../../a.txt
/tmp/x/y/z $ rm ../../a.txt
/tmp/x/y/z $ rfind a.txt || echo "not found."
rfind: file a.txt not found
not found.
```